# why are input values show incorrect?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstNameInput">Firstname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameInput" name="firstNameInput">

        <label for="lastNameInput">Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameInput" name="lastNameInput">            
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="showName()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var person = {
        firstName:document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value,
        lastName:document.getElementById('lastNameInput').value,
        fullName: function () {return this.firstNameInput + ", " + this.lastNameInput;}
    };

    function showName() {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = person.fullName();
    };
</script>
```

why are input values show incorrect?
//now result are ==> undefined, undefined
Please help me to find my wrong code!

Comment: I don't understand your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DizzyEgg After click on the button; instead of values in the inputs, only shows "undefined, undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the variable name you used is not correct

```
return this.firstNameInput + ", " + this.lastNameInput;
```

It is `this.firstName` not `this.firstNameInput`

Next : if you declare the `person` outside the function, the `firstName` and `lastName` will have `null` value since the input element have no value on page load.

You have to declare the `person` inside the function, so that the values in input fields are assigned to `firstName` and `lastName` on button click.

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstNameInput">Firstname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameInput" name="firstNameInput">

        <label for="lastNameInput">Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameInput" name="lastNameInput">            
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="showName()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    

    function showName() {
      
      var person = {
        firstName: document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value,
        lastName: document.getElementById('lastNameInput').value,
        fullName: function () {return this.firstName + ", " + this.lastName;}
        };
      
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = person.fullName();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the persons object, you directly ask for the value of the input fields. When this happens, the user did not have the time to insert a value. What you should do is ask for the value in your `fullName` function. See this example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstNameInput">Firstname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameInput" name="firstNameInput">

        <label for="lastNameInput">Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameInput" name="lastNameInput">            
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="showName()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var person = {
        firstNameElement: document.getElementById('firstNameInput'),
        lastNameElement: document.getElementById('lastNameInput'),
        fullName: function () {
            return this.firstNameElement.value + ", " + this.lastNameElement.value;
        }
    };

    function showName() {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = person.fullName();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your Answer, my mistake was ==> `this.firstName` not `this.firstNameInput`

Comment: It was a combination of both I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I think var person should be declared inside the ShowName function if you want to get the ements input value. There' s probably a cleaner way of doing that...